# OSX Vanitygen error: pattern.c:32:10: fatal error: 'pcre.h' file not found

Tags: development, mac, vanity-address, vanitygen

I get the error below when I try to [make vanitygen according to the instructions listed in "install"](https://github.com/samr7/vanitygen/blob/master/INSTALL)

**Error from make** (short version)

```
27 warnings generated.
cc -ggdb -O3 -Wall   -c -o pattern.o pattern.c
pattern.c:32:10: fatal error: 'pcre.h' file not found
#include <pcre.h>
         ^
1 error generated.
```

**Full output of make**

```
my-MacBook-Pro:git-vanitygen admin$ make
cc -ggdb -O3 -Wall   -c -o vanitygen.o vanitygen.c
vanitygen.c:76:11: warning: 'EC_KEY_get0_group' is deprecated
      [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
        pgroup = EC_KEY_get0_group(pkey);
                 ^
vanitygen.c:77:9: warning: 'EC_GROUP_get0_generator' is deprecated
      [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
        pgen = EC_GROUP_get0_generator(pgroup);
               ^
vanitygen.c:80:13: warning: 'EC_POINT_new' is deprecated
      [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
                ppnt[i] = EC_POINT_new(pgroup);
                          ^
vanitygen.c:86:14: warning: 'EC_POINT_new' is deprecated
      [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
        pbatchinc = EC_POINT_new(pgroup);
                    ^
vanitygen.c:92:2: warning: 'BN_set_word' is deprecated
      [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
        BN_set_word(&vxcp->vxc_bntmp, ptarraysize);
        ^
vanitygen.c:93:2: warning: 'EC_POINT_mul' is deprecated
      [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
        EC_POINT_mul(pgroup, pbatchinc, &vxcp->vxc_bntmp, NULL, NULL,
        ^
vanitygen.c:95:2: warning: 'EC_POINT_make_affine' is deprecated
      [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
        EC_POINT_make_affine(pgroup, pbatchinc, vxcp->vxc_bnctx);
        ^
vanitygen.c:124:4: warning: 'EC_KEY_generate_key' is deprecated
      [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
                        EC_KEY_generate_key(pkey);
                        ^
vanitygen.c:128:4: warning: 'EC_GROUP_get_order' is deprecated
      [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
                        EC_GROUP_get_order(pgroup, &vxcp->vxc_bntmp,
                        ^
vanitygen.c:130:4: warning: 'BN_sub' is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
                        BN_sub(&vxcp->vxc_bntmp2,
                        ^
vanitygen.c:132:11: warning: 'EC_KEY_get0_private_key' is deprecated
      [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
                               EC_KEY_get0_private_key(pkey));
                               ^
vanitygen.c:133:15: warning: 'BN_get_word' is deprecated
      [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
                        rekey_at = BN_get_word(&vxcp->vxc_bntmp2);
                                   ^
vanitygen.c:138:4: warning: 'EC_POINT_copy' is deprecated
      [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
                        EC_POINT_copy(ppnt[0], EC_KEY_get0_public_key(pkey));
                        ^
vanitygen.c:138:27: warning: 'EC_KEY_get0_public_key' is deprecated
      [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
                        EC_POINT_copy(ppnt[0], EC_KEY_get0_public_key(pkey));
                                               ^
vanitygen.c:145:5: warning: 'EC_POINT_add' is deprecated
      [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
                                EC_POINT_add(pgroup,
                                ^
vanitygen.c:154:5: warning: 'EC_POINT_add' is deprecated
      [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
                                EC_POINT_add(pgroup,
                                ^
vanitygen.c:173:5: warning: 'EC_POINT_add' is deprecated
      [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
                                EC_POINT_add(pgroup,
                                ^
vanitygen.c:192:3: warning: 'EC_POINTs_make_affine' is deprecated
      [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
                EC_POINTs_make_affine(pgroup, nbatch, ppnt, vxcp->vxc_bnctx);
                ^
vanitygen.c:196:10: warning: 'EC_POINT_point2oct' is deprecated
      [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
                        len = EC_POINT_point2oct(pgroup, ppnt[i],
                              ^
vanitygen.c:203:4: warning: 'SHA256' is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
                        SHA256(hash_buf, hash_len, hash1);
                        ^
vanitygen.c:204:4: warning: 'RIPEMD160' is deprecated
      [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
                        RIPEMD160(hash1, sizeof(hash1), &vxcp->vxc_binres[1]);
                        ^
vanitygen.c:236:4: warning: 'EC_POINT_free' is deprecated
      [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
                        EC_POINT_free(ppnt[i]);
                        ^
vanitygen.c:238:3: warning: 'EC_POINT_free' is deprecated
      [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
                EC_POINT_free(pbatchinc);
                ^
vanitygen.c:419:18: warning: 'EC_POINT_hex2point' is deprecated
      [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
                        pubkey_base = EC_POINT_hex2point(
                                      ^
vanitygen.c:420:5: warning: 'EC_KEY_get0_group' is deprecated
      [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
                                EC_KEY_get0_group(pkey),
                                ^
vanitygen.c:422:4: warning: 'EC_KEY_free' is deprecated
      [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
                        EC_KEY_free(pkey);
                        ^
vanitygen.c:528:9: warning: 'RAND_load_file' is deprecated
      [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
                opt = RAND_load_file(seedfile, opt);
                      ^
27 warnings generated.
cc -ggdb -O3 -Wall   -c -o pattern.o pattern.c
pattern.c:32:10: fatal error: 'pcre.h' file not found
#include <pcre.h>
         ^
1 error generated.
make: *** [pattern.o] Error 1
```

---

**UPDATE**

I suspect that PCRE that is listed [also has a OSX port that is listed here](http://www.pcre.org), and when I compile according to the instructions I get this error:

```
make  install-am
 ./install-sh -c -d '/usr/local/lib'
 /bin/sh ./libtool   --mode=install /usr/bin/install -c   libpcre.la libpcreposix.la libpcrecpp.la '/usr/local/lib'
libtool: install: /usr/bin/install -c .libs/libpcre.1.dylib /usr/local/lib/libpcre.1.dylib
install: /usr/local/lib/libpcre.1.dylib: Permission denied
make[2]: *** [install-libLTLIBRARIES] Error 71
make[1]: *** [install-am] Error 2
make: *** [install] Error 2
```

Comment: To those voting off-topic, this question does not seem substantially different from the many other questions tagged "vanitygen".  If **all** questions of this type are going to be considered off-topic, that consideration should probably start with a meta post.  Voting to leave open for now.

Comment: You need to type 'sudo make install' instead of 'make install' to install PCRE properly.

Answer (score 9):

I would recommend using Homebrew or MacPorts to manage this dependency.

The Homebrew package is simply `pcre` or `pcre++`.

```
brew install pcre pcre++
```

The MacPorts packages are `pcre` and `pcrexx`.

```
sudo port install pcre pcrexx
```

Comment: The corresponding macports packages are `pcre` and `pcrexx`

Comment: Of note, if you've installed a new version of XCode, you will need to install the corresponding Command Line Tools for `/usr/local/includes` to be in the search path of your compiler. This is where Homebrew and MacPorts would have put the `pcre.h` file.

Comment: `pcre++` is not needed.

Answer (score 3):

just in case anyone still looking for an answer: in pattern.c just put the full path to pcre.h (use locate pcre.h to find a path for it; if you don't have the file just install pcre package first). It should compile fine afterwards.